# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetcherError::SSL_connect returned=1 erno=0 state=SSLw3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rubygems

I have been having this error for a while. I am using Ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.1.8. I am getting the error in the question title whenever I run the commands:

```
1 rails new app
2 gem install..
```

I run 1 (rails new app) and the error was:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetcherError::SSL_connect returned=1 erno=0 state=SSLw3.....certificate failed https://rubygems.org/gem/rake-10.4.2.gem.
An error occurred while installing rake <10.4.2> and bunler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before bundling.
```

I try running 2 (gem install rake) and I got a similar error:

```
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/- SSL_connect returned=1 erno=0 state=SSLw3....server certificate failed.
```

What is going wrong ? Does it have to do with my internet security ?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, I'm also not sure what happened. Maybe one of the gem providers changed the certs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/

gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Remove the secure URL, add an unsecure one. My gems are now updating without issues.